# PintOS proj2 userprog Kernel Panic in formatting the file system partition

Tags: c, pintos

> pintos -f -q

This command will cause this error

> 00000000000i[     ] reading configuration from bochsrc.txt
>   00000000000e[     ] bochsrc.txt:8: 'user_shortcut' will be replaced by
>   new 'keyboard' option. 00000000000i[     ] installing nogui module as
>   the Bochs GUI 00000000000i[     ] using log file bochsout.txt PiLo
>   hda1 Loading.......... Kernel command line: -f -q Kernel PANIC at
>   ../../threads/vaddr.h:84 in vtop(): assertion `is_kernel_vaddr
>   (vaddr)' failed. Call stack: 0xc0028d9f.

Answer (score -1):

here is my answer to this question. I am just too lazy to type it again after I typed it in Piazza.

[image]

[image]